# How to use variables in a switch statement?

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I have about 50 files that I need to call within `dataSource1`, `dataSource2`, and `dataSource3`.  Instead of copying it all out into each `switch` statement, how can I use variables so I only have to type it out once at the top of the code?  I am calling this within `server.R` for a Shiny App.

```
dataSource1 <- reactive({
        switch(input$dataSelection1,
               "File1" = File1,
               "File2" = File2,
               "File3" = File3,
               "File50" = File50
)
        )
```

Instead, I would like to have:

```
dataSource1 <- reactive({
            switch(input$dataSelection1,
                   FileNumber = File
                   )
        )
dataSource2 <- reactive({
            switch(input$dataSelection1,
                   FileNumber = File
                   )
        )
dataSource2 <- reactive({
            switch(input$dataSelection1,
                   FileNumber = File
                   )
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `get` function that will return the value of a named object. Assuming that `input$dataSelection1` has the complete name of the variable, your reactive function could be something like this:

```
 dataSource1 <- reactive({
            get(input$dataSelection1)
        )
```

It will return the content of the variable that match the name.

If `input$dataSelection1` only contains a number, you can use the `paste0` or `sprintf` functions to build the name of the variable:

```
get(paste0('File',input$dataSelection1)) # it will create File1, File2...
sprintf('File%04d',input$dataSelection1) # add zeros before the number File0001
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Geovany.  I have one more question for you.  I have appended it to the original question.  Thanks for your help!